# Setting marker from geoloc with address from textbox

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have this part of code. 
I want to put marker, when text in textbox will change - it works with function changeValue() - getting new address.

Then, I want to put this marker, when address variable will change. How do to it?

I tried with this code below, but I get this error:
`Error: ReferenceError: changeValue is not defined`
What is wrong?

```
     (...)
    <asp:TextBox Style="width: 300px;" runat="server" ID="tbStreet" onchange="changeValue()"></asp:TextBox>
     (...) // more 5 textboxes

   <script type='text/javascript'>
          (...) // 2 long string arrays.

        var address;
        function mapaStart() {
            var wspolrzedne = new google.maps.LatLng(52.22105994970536, 19.22609921875007);
            var opcjeMapy = {
                zoom: 5,
                center: wspolrzedne,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapka"), opcjeMapy);


        function changeValue() {

            var ulica;
            var miasto;
            var woj1;
            var panstwo1;
            ulica = document.getElementById("<%=tbStreet.ClientID%>").value;
            miasto = document.getElementById("<%=tbCity.ClientID%>").value;
            woj1 = woj[document.getElementById("<%=ddlProvince.ClientID%>").value];
            panstwo1 = panstwa[document.getElementById("<%=ddlCountry.ClientID%>").value];
            address = panstwo1 + ", " + woj1 + ", " + miasto + ", " + ulica;
            alert(address);
        }   
            var geokoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            map.setCenter(address.geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                {
                    map: map,
                    position: address.geometry.location,
                }
            );

        } 

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your changeValue function is local to the mapaStart function.  It is not accessible in the global context that HTML click/onchange listeners run in.  To make it global, move it outside of the mapaStart function.

Comment: but, what if I have to have function changeValue inside mapaStart?

Comment: You wrote "but what if I have to have function changeValue inside mapaStart".  Maybe you could explain why you believe that to be true,  I don't understand why that would be.  The changeValue function has to be in the global context to be accessible as an onchange function.